# Web API 2 Attribute Routing : AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

Hi below is my scenario

I have PersonController with method CreatePerson

```
[ApiVersion(ApiControllerVersion.Version1)]
    public class PersonController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/person")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(ErrorServiceResponse))]
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorServiceResponse))]
        [SwaggerOperation("POST: Create Person")]
        [ValidateModelState]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePerson([FromBody][Required] CreatePersonRequest person)
        {
        }

        [HttpPut]
        [Route("/person")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(ErrorServiceResponse))]
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorServiceResponse))]
        [SwaggerOperation("POST: Change Person")]
        [ValidateModelState]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePerson([FromBody][Required] UpdatePersonRequest person)
        {
        }
    }
```

I wanted to create another version of this API so created like below coz my create Route changed. 
Where I am inheriting PersonController coz I want all the methods from V1 and changed from v2 except "CreatePerson"

```
[ApiVersion(ApiControllerVersion.Version2)]
    public class PersonControllerV2 : PersonController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/persons")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(ErrorServiceResponse))]
        [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorServiceResponse))]
        [SwaggerOperation("POST: Create Person")]
        [ValidateModelState]
        public new async Task<IActionResult> CreatePerson([FromBody][Required] CreatePersonRequest person)
        {
        }
    }
```

If I don't change route I can see V1 POST /person and V2 POST /person are running fine however

when I change my V2 route to "/persons" from "/person" for CreatePerson as per my requirement then I am getting below error while calling V1 POST /person from swagger

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
Controllers.PersonControllerV2.CreatePerson
Controllers.PersonController.CreatePerson

In this case my

**V1 swagger shows**

- POST /person
- PUT /person

**V2 swagger shows**

- POST /persons
- POST /person
- PUT /person

Any Idea or suggestion to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you didn't specify `[ApiController]` before `[ApiVersion(ApiControllerVersion.Version1)]` and `[ApiVersion(ApiControllerVersion.Version2)]`.

So you should change like this:

```
[ApiController] 
[ApiVersion(ApiControllerVersion.Version1)]
    public class PersonController : BaseController
    {...

[ApiController] 
[ApiVersion(ApiControllerVersion.Version2)]
    public class PersonControllerV2 : PersonController
    {...
```